# Is it permissible to use money found on the street?

Tags: fiqh, money

Is it halal to use the money you found on the street when nobody is around anymore? What if I send it to the police and then someone makes a fake claim?

Comment: I would think it is quite difficult to make fake claims. 1) The person will need to know the exact amount of the money lost. 2) The person will need to know the exact location where it was lost. Having said that, it would be better if you can take it to the police so maybe the person who lost it has also reported to police. If it is not a large sum, I don't take it; the person who lost it might come back looking for it and find it, or someone else who needs it may take it after me. If it is a large sum, I would take and bring to the police.

Answer (score 3):

No it is not. The money still belongs to the person who lost it and you do not have their consent to use it.

> ياأيها الذين آمنوا لا تأكلوا أموالكم بينكم بالباطل إلا أن تكون تجارة عن تراض منكم
>
> O you who have believed, do not consume one another's wealth unjustly but only [in lawful] business by mutual consent.
>
> <sup>— [Quran 4:29](https://quran.com/4/29)</sup>

Found property is called اللقطة (al-Luqtah) and there are detailed rules in Islam on how to to deal with it, chapters may be found on it in [Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/45) and [Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim/31) and in books of fiqh etc.

In short, you need to announce the found property for a year so that the owner can find it. After that you may give it as charity on behalf of the owner. If the owner is ever found you need to return it.

Regarding your concern of a fake claim, some details regarding the property are withheld and the claimant is asked about them to verify their ownership.

> أن رجلا سأل رسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلم عن اللقطة قال عرفها سنة ثم اعرف وكاءها وعفاصها ثم استنفق بها فإن جاء ربها فأدها إليه
>
> A man asked Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) about the Luqata. He said, "Make public announcement of it for one year, then remember the description of its container and the string it is tied with, utilize the money, and if its owner comes back after that, give it to him."
>
> <sup>—[Bukhari](http://sunnah.com/bukhari/45/11)</sup>
>
> فإن جاء أحد يخبرك بعددها ووعائها ووكائها فأعطها إياه
>
> If someone comes and informs you about the number (of articles) of the bag and the straps, then give that to him
>
> <sup>—[Muslim](http://sunnah.com/muslim/31/10)</sup>

Answer (score -3):

That's basically stealing, which is strictly prophibited in Islam.
Allah says: **“[As for] the thief, the male and the female, amputate their hands in recompense for what they earned [i.e. committed] as a deterrent [punishment] from Allah. And Allah is Exalted in Might and Wise.” [Quran 5:38]  **
The reason the punishment is that, is because it scares people from stealing, meaning less people will steal.

Comment: Theft is taking something by stealth from a place of safe custody. The hadd will not apply to someone who picks up something from the street.

Comment: How could this be stealing? Can you explain..