# Money found on road

Tags: money

When I was infront of the mosque near by accomodation in Qatar, I found 1500 Indian money(INR). Since I did'nt know the islamic ruling on the money found on road, I thought I will give this money for charity in India. But, when I read about the ruling on that, I am little worried. Announcing at the place that I got money will be difficult. because of language problems. Also. I can't give it for charity here in Qatar because its indian money. So in this situation wgat is the best thing to do? Is it permissible to replace it from where I got the money? Kindly suggest the best.
Thanks in Advance 
Jazakallah khair
Assalamu alikum

Comment: Relevant: [Is it permissible to use money found on the street?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/49304)

Answer (score 1):

Read the Islamic ruling [here](https://www.islamweb.net/en/article/135453/the-islamic-ruling-on-al-luqatah-lost-and-found).

If I were you, I'd announce it for a year (in both Arabic and Indian language - asking for help from native speakers as needed) and if no one claims it then get it exchanged for Qatari money and give it in charity on the owner's behalf. If the owner later shows up, give him an equivalent in his money back and the charity will then be on my behalf.

وعليكم السلام ورحمة الله وبركاته

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you talk with the Imam of the the mosque, he can make an announcement near prayer time and you have better chance to find the owner this way.